leftpane region is null in Case -> Audit getActivities() when making case report
When making case report with all activities, AuditConfig -> sort() is prompting uasort parameter null error instead of array. Initial finding is that in
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/137cd8116647b5dde72f1bfbceb0154fe9c88141/CRM/Case/Audit/Audit.php#L138, leftpane is not an array or is actually null, which causes the error.
CiviCRM: 5.71.1

There is a PR sent yesterday for the above fix, Can you apply the patch?

SOLVED: Used the patch for now.

Thanks for letting us know that this fixed your issue. Rather than post a comment could you please mark Pradeep's answer as the accepted answer. Thanks!  See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer
